# MediumTopBar does not work as expected and second line has white background color

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Let's see if someone can help me. In this Jetpack Compose code the second line of the MediumTopBar appears with white background color instead of the defined background color, why can it be. Thank you very much.

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        MediumTopAppBar(
            title = { Text(
                text = tituloLista,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable { clickableTopBar() }
            ) },
            actions = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = navProdutos
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.outline_add_circle_24),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.add_circle),
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = navCategorias
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.outline_library_add_24),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.library_add),
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = navCesta
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.outline_shopping_cart_24),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.shopping_cart),
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { showConfirmationDialog = true }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.outline_delete_forever_24),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.delete_forever),
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { (context as? Activity)?.finish() }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.outline_power_settings_new_24),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.power_settings),
                    )
                }
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.mediumTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = currentTopBarColor,
                titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                actionIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                scrolledContainerColor = currentTopBarColor
            ),
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
        )
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    Surface (
```

If I use TopBar instead of MediumTopBar everything goes correctly but I need to put a longer title, that's why the MediumTopBar gives it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a library bug. I have fixed it by changing the version:

implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha12")

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the second line of MediumTopAppBar in your Jetpack Compose code having a white background could be due to several reasons:
Check currentTopBarColor Value: Ensure that the currentTopBarColor variable is correctly set and not being overridden elsewhere in your code.
Scroll Behavior: Verify that the scrollBehavior you are using does not affect the top bar's background color.
Parent Layouts: If your top bar is within other layouts, check if these layouts are influencing its background color.
Hardcoded Color Test: Temporarily replace currentTopBarColor with a hardcoded color (like Color.Blue) to check if the issue is with the color variable itself.
State Updates in Compose: Ensure the state of your composables is updating correctly, as Compose UI elements rely on state changes to redraw.
Jetpack Compose Version: Use the latest stable version of Jetpack Compose to avoid bugs from earlier versions.
Testing on Different Devices/Emulators: Sometimes rendering issues can be device-specific, so test on different setups.
Isolating the MediumTopAppBar in a simple setup can also help identify if the problem is with the AppBar configuration or other parts of your UI code.

Comment: OK. I will try everything you suggest.

Comment: I have removed the rest of the code from the screen (it is the main screen) and the problem persists.
I have also checked the colors using hardcoded color and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).